# how to use data from 2 tables and combine it in one?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables 1 is Lookup and another is Details.

**Lookup Table**

```
Identity Type   Value

200 Entity  A
201 Entity  B
202 Entity  C
203 Entity  D
300 SOURCE  X
301 SOURCE  y
```

**Details Table**

```
Sender(int) Reciever(int)   Source(int) State(varchar)
200             203             300             hongkong
```

In the Details table Sender, Reciever are the Entity in Lookup table with Identity as their ids.

My problem is that when I write the query as `Select Sender,Reciever,Source,State from Details` I am getting `200,203,300,hongkong` but I want the result as `A,D,X,hongkong`.
Please help.

Comment: Are you using the ["one true lookup table"](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/philfactor/archive/2008/05/29/56525.aspx) anti pattern?

Comment: I am not getting what you  are saying.Please explain clearly

Comment: There is a link in my comment if you want further explanation.

Comment: @@Martin Smith: love that anti-pattern!!  Seen it used in practice and the creator would not be convinced otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tSen.[Value] as [Sender], tRec.[Value] as [Reciever]
, tSou.[Value] as [Source], D.[State] 
FROM Details as D 
JOIN Lookup as tSen ON D.Sender = tSen.Identity 
JOIN Lookup as tRec ON D.Reciever = tRec.Identity 
JOIN Lookup as tSou ON D.Source = tSou.Identity
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JOIN for both tables. It's base SQL syntax

Comment: Can u please give some example? It will be really helpful.